# Stacked bar chart using jquery in ASP.Net using C#?

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I want to create a stacked bar chart using query. I have already done the chart using static values, but I have now to do it with dynamic values.

I am using the flot plugin, if any other plugin is good or feasible please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for the **[Fusion Charts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/)** (Flash based charts with animation) to show it with jquery and asp.net.

They have [jquery plugin](http://www.fusioncharts.com/jquery/) to show the charts using jquery.

You can find more info on [Link1](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/demos/), [Link2](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/gallery/) and [Link3](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/Default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Stacked bar chart can be implemented in C# and ASP.net itself no need to go for third party Charts.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
MobileSalesChart.Series["Apple"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Apple"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Nokia"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Nokia"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Samsung"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Samsung"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Sony"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Sony"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series["Motorola"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(i, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Motorola"].ToString().Trim()));
MobileSalesChart.Series[0].Points[i].AxisLabel = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Year"].ToString().Trim();
}
```

Reference [Click Here](http://www.fourthbottle.com/2014/12/how-to-create-stacked-bar-chart-using.html)